# Mat-select control is not working in html

Tags: angular, select, mat-select

When trying to use mat-select in html....it is not working.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-select>
        <mat-option value="one">First option</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="two">Second option</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Results are displayed like below

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDZ7a.png)

P.S I have imported `import {MatNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material/core';` and added `MatNativeDateModule` under imports in app.module.ts files

After adding MatSelectModule in app.module.ts file and imports section, Now select control and options are not visible.

Below is my app.module.ts file

```
import { NgModule,CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import {MatNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[Select control not visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXl6z.png)
[Disturb UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bi1aD.png)

Comment: add label too `<mat-label>Label</mat-label>`

Comment: <mat-label>Label</mat-label> is of no use aas it only adds label in form field but Select control not visible in html

Comment: why did you change the default styles?

Comment: are you using this select in `AppComponent`?

Comment: no i didnt change any default styles....

Comment: yup i am using the select in app component

Comment: that's weird... can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: @Mahdijoon sure just a min as i am new to stackblitz it will take some time

Comment: @Mahdijoon I am attachnig stackblitz url FYR .  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-czjs8m?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to add Angular Material core theme. You can add one of the pre-built theme by adding an entry within the styles array of your project's `angular.json` file as:

```json
"build": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
  "options": {
    ...
    "assets": [
      ...
    ],
    "styles": [
      "src/styles.scss",
      "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"
    ],
 ...
}
```

After adding the above entry, for changes to be reflected you should restart the server.

If you are still facing issue, you can try adding the theme within your global `styles.css` file as:

```css
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

You can refer https://material.angular.io/guide/theming to explore more.

Comment: i have tried adding as suggestd by you but still its not working

Comment: @raghav You can import the theme within `styles.css` file. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

this is the part you have to remove from your `css`:

```
:host {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

but in general your `css` is causing this situation.

Comment: i hve imported that as well but problem is now only dropdown icon is coming and neither control nor data is coming. I am adding another screenshot FYR. in my post

Comment: I am adding my app.module.ts file as well can u pls tell if something else needs to be added...boz now once i click on select dropdown complete UI got disturbs

Comment: This is one of the most weird things I've ever seen. Removing the styles will make it better but the label will not be hidden on select!

Comment: thanks to u too from deep of my heart

Comment: I didn't fix it at least... no need for thank you