# Mat-options are shown after other component in Angular Material (Custom Theme)

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-select, mat-option

Derived from this question:
[Change style Select Angular Material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70748258/change-style-select-angular-material)

I face this problem with Angular Material, specifically with `mat-select` and its `mat-options`: The mat-options are shown after other components.

[image]

I need to show the options just after the its `place holder` above the component below (hinding it); not after nor between!
For this case, The blue rectangle should be hidden by the green one.

Here my code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-buotqn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcore%2Fcomponents%2Flayout%2Flayout.component.html

**how to show the list of options above the component below and below the place-holder of the select?**

Comment: See if this helps -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70641097/mat-select-control-is-not-working-in-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the material styles are not active.
Adding

`@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";`

to your style.css should fix your problem.

This sets one of the default themes, if you want to build your own theme the documentation can be found here: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Comment: Thanks!!!!
I was trying to reach something like https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiWNH.png

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you imported @angular/theme?

check this: [Angular Theme](https://v10.material.angular.io/guide/theming)