# Angular Material v11 not working properly

Tags: angular

I am trying to use Angular Material version 11.2.2 in my project. I used npm install @angular/material@11 @angular/cdk@11 to do the install. I did not get the prompt to choose a style or theme or anything, it just went through the process of installation. I have imported the MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule and MatSelectModule into app.module.ts and have @import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" in my component.scss but, when I try to use matInput and mat-select it renders weirdly. Will appreciate if you let me know what I might have missed.

[Here is my package.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8z1l.png)

[Here is how it renders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31o7q.png)

Comment: [Import theme css in global styles.scss file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70641968/9471852)

Comment: I have added @import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css'; to styles.scss  and added below to angular.json. Still not working                           
 "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/styles.css",
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"
            ],